# Ограничение типа классов в generic классе. C#

Tags: c#, java, generics

В Java в шаблоне класса можно указать, от какого класса должен наследоваться класс или для какого класса он является супер классом.  Вот так

public class FormalVector<E> extends Vector{}

Как подобные ограничения можно наложить в C# шаблонах?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если хотите накладывать ограничения на T:

```
class FormalVector<T> where T : SomeClass
{ ... }
```

Для случаев с несколькими параметрами:

```
class Foo<T, U>
    where T : IComparable, ICloneable
    where U: IDisposable
{ }
```

Стоит отметить, что в отличие от Java, ограничить `T` предками какого-то класса в C# невозможно.

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнение по вопросу:    
- Как указать, что класс Т является предком SomeClass
- Если у меня надо указать несколько классов, то это будет так     
 where T : SomeClass, К : OtherClass.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Наверное, просто

```
public class FormalVector<E> : Vector
{
    ...
```

?

(Насколько я понимаю, ваш пример не накладывает ограничения на `E`.)

---

Для конструкции

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem)
```

аналогом будет

```
public static int countGreaterThan<T>(T[] anArray, T elem) where T : IComparable<T>
```

---

А вообще, такую функцию писать самому не надо, она уже есть в LINQ:

```
int count = array.Count(x => x > elem);
```

или

```
int count = array.Count(x => x.CompareTo(elem) > 0);
```

Работает не только с массивами, но и с любым `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Немного не то имел ввиду, Извиняюсь. 

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) 
    {
     return 0;
    }

Вот таким образом наложить ограничение

Comment: @alex91: обновил